# Deriving a commutator in quantum field theory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, operators, fourier-transform, commutator

I am studying quantum field theory through the Peskin and Schroeder book. I have the following two equations

$$[\phi(x),\pi(x')] = \int \frac{d^3p\ d^3p'}{(2\pi)^6}\frac{-i}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\omega_{\vec{p\ '}}}{\omega_{\vec{p}}}}([a^\dagger_{-\vec{p}},a_{\vec{p}\ '}] - [a_{\vec{p}},a^\dagger_{-\vec{p}\ '}])e^{i(\vec{p}.\vec{x}+\vec{p\ '}.\vec{x\ '})}$$

$$[a_{\vec{p}}, a^\dagger_{\vec{p\ '}}] = (2\pi)^3 \delta^{(3)}(\vec{p} - \vec{p'})$$

How do I combine the above two equations to get the following equation?

$$[\phi(x),\pi(x')] = i \delta^{(3)}(\vec{x} - \vec{x'})$$

Comment: Everything you need to do is right in front of you. What precisely is the trouble you are having?

Comment: An equality $A=B$ is a license to replace $A$ by $B$ in any statement involving $A$. So replace the commutators in 1st eq by RHS of 2nd equation then do the computation using the main rule about deltas eating up an integration, etc., etc.

Comment: Have you seen this: $\int_{-\infty}^\infty d^3p\,e^{i p\cdot x} = (2\pi)^3\delta^{(3)}(x)$?